# Remove prefix from SOAP request using JAX WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm building a SOAP Web service using JAXWS way. When I deploy the project and check the request using SOAP UI, I see some of the prefix which I dont want. Can any one let me know how to overcome this issue?

Here is my code

```
@WebService
public interface Transaction {

    @WebMethod(action="createPurchase", operationName = "purchase")
    ResultDto purchase(@WebParam(name = "PurchaseRequest") PurchaseRequest request) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException;

}
```

### PurchaseRequest class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "PurchaseRequest")
public class PurchaseRequest implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@XmlElement(name = "invoiceId", required = true)
protected String invoiceId;
// Getters and setters
}
```

When I give the wsdl in SOAP UI, this is the request formed

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.qiib.com/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ser:purchase> --> namespace
     <!--Optional:-->
     <PurchaseRequest>
        <invoiceId>?</invoiceId>           
     </PurchaseRequest>
  </ser:purchase>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And you see the prefix `<ser` :I dont want this `ser:` as prefix, can I have just

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this mean? `'ad you see the namespace`. There is no namespace there as it is already qualified by prefix `ser:purchase` and ser is defined in root element

Comment: @Optional, I mean I dont want the namespace pre, updated the question too

Comment: if you don't want namespace prefix then you need to move `xmlns:ser="http://service.qiib.com/"` from root element and move to `<purchase xmlns="http://service.qiib.com/"` directly. 

But why do you want to do that, both the xml is valid? Is it because you are not able to handle at client because of prefix or something like that?

Comment: @Optional, exactly, they want in plain tags without prefixes. Let me try what you say

Comment: I didnt get your point --> move xmlns:ser="http://service.qiib.com/" from root element and move to <purchase xmlns="http://service.qiib.com/"

Comment: Why they want in plain tags when both is valid xml. Any way, what i meant is in line `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.qiib.com/">` remove `xmlns:ser="http://service.qiib.com/"` and change line `<ser:purchase> ` to `<purchase xmlns="http://service.qiib.com"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159361/discussion-between-yakhoob-and-optional).